# Why won't my jQuery date of birth validation script not work?

Tags: jquery

I'm making a script that is meant to check if the date of birth has been input correctly.
I've been trying to locate my error for much time by now, but with no success. Can you please help?
Code fragment is down below.

```
   $(document).on('keyup',"input#signup_dob_input",function(){
        var this_user_input=$("input[name='signup_dob_input']").val();
        var first_dot_position = this_user_input.indexOf(".");
        var second_dot_position = this_user_input.indexOf(".",3);
        var dob_correct_length = 10;
        var first_integer_check_substr = this_user_input.substr(0,1);
        var second_integer_check_substr = this_user_input.substr(3,4);
        var third_integer_check_substr = this_user_input.substr(6,9);
        var first_integer = parseInt(first_integer_check_substr);
        var second_integer = parseInt(second_integer_check_substr);
        var third_integer = parseInt(third_integer_check_substr);
        var current_date_object = new Date();
        var current_year = current_date_object.getFullYear();

        if ((first_dot_position!=-1)&&(second_dot_position!=-1)&&(this_user_input.length==dob_correct_length)&&((first_integer>0)&&(first_integer<=31))&&((second_integer>0)&&(second_integer<=12))&&(third integer<=current_year)){

        $('#feedback_message_signup6').css({"visibility": "visible", "color": "#347C17"});
        $('#feedback_message_signup6').html('Верный формат даты');}
        else {
        $('#feedback_message_signup6').css({"visibility": "visible", "color": "#CC0000"});
        $('#feedback_message_signup6').html('Неверный формат даты');
}
    });
```

Comment: `third integer` should be `third_integer` in your `if` statement. Also, remember to [always use a `radix`](http://jslinterrors.com/missing-radix-parameter/) when using `parseInt`.

Comment: Have you considering using a `RegExp` instead?

Comment: It's much better to use a RegExp, of course. Thanks guys, it will work now.

Comment: So, can we come up with a regex solution, if you tell us the format of the date you are expecting?

Comment: i think I'm good with these conditions as for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in 'third integer' variable, missing the underscore.

```
if (
                    (first_dot_position!=-1) &&
                        (second_dot_position!=-1)&&
                        (this_user_input.length==dob_correct_length)&&
                        ((first_integer>0)&&
                        (first_integer<=31))&&
                        ((second_integer>0)&&
                        (second_integer<=12))&&
                        (**third_integer**<=current_year)
                    ){
```

see my code: http://jsfiddle.net/Magicianred/3k5tS/

Enjoy your code!
Simone